# What could be the good way to check if N optionals returning from different functions all have values

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Let say I have a code like that

```
#include <string>
#include <optional>
#include <charconv>

std::optional<int> get_1(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? 1 : std::optional<int>{}; }
std::optional<const char*> get_2(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? "2" : std::optional<const char*>{}; }
std::optional<double> get_3(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? 3.0 : std::optional<double>{}; }
std::optional<int64_t> get_4(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? -10000000000 : std::optional<int64_t>{}; }
std::optional<std::string> get_5(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? "5" : std::optional<std::string>{}; }
// ..... more functions like that

struct S {
    int a1;
    const char* a2;
    double a3;
    int64_t a4;
    std::string a5;
private:
    int AGR_INIT_IS_NOT_ALLOWED{0};
};

std::optional<S> getS() {
    S s;
    // Now I'd like to return std::nullopt if any of the following calls return std::nullopt
    // The naive way to do that is smth like that

    if (auto val = get_1("A"); val) {
        s.a1 = *val;
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    if (auto val = get_2("A"); val) {
        s.a2 = *val;
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    if (auto val = get_3("A"); val) {
        s.a3 = *val;
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    if (auto val = get_4("A"); val) {
        s.a4 = *val;
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    if (auto val = get_5("A"); val) {
        s.a5 = *val;
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    return !getS();
}
```

Now my question is, can anyone advice on how to get rid of code replication inside `getS` function? Any pattern or smth that would work here?

The first obvious "solution" is instead of returning an optional just throw an exception inside `get_*` and then catch it in `getS`

```
#include <string>
#include <optional>
#include <charconv>
#include <exception>

int get_1(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? 1 :throw std::exception{};}
const char* get_2(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? "2" : throw std::exception{}; }
double get_3(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? 3.0 : throw std::exception{}; }
int64_t get_4(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? -10000000000 : throw std::exception{}; }
std::string get_5(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? "5" : throw std::exception{}; }
// ..... more functions like that

struct S {
    int a1;
    const char* a2;
    double a3;
    int64_t a4;
    std::string a5;
private:
    int AGR_INIT_IS_NOT_ALLOWED{0};
};

std::optional<S> getS() {
    S s;
    try {
        s.a1 = get_1("A");
        s.a2 = get_2("A");
        s.a3 = get_3("A");
        s.a4 = get_4("A");
        s.a5 = get_5("A");
    } catch (const std::exception&) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    return !getS();
}
```

I can't use exceptions, so it's not a solution at all (not to mention it is silly to refactor all these methods). Though, for now to me it looks like the best option it terms of avoiding boilerplate.

The second "solution" I was thinking about is to put all the optionals into tuple first, check if all them hold values and then assign from the tuple like that:

```
#include <string>
#include <optional>
#include <tuple>


std::optional<int> get_1(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? 1 : std::optional<int>{}; }
std::optional<const char*> get_2(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? "2" : std::optional<const char*>{}; }
std::optional<double> get_3(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? 3.0 : std::optional<double>{}; }
std::optional<int64_t> get_4(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? -10000000000 : std::optional<int64_t>{}; }
std::optional<std::string> get_5(const std::string& s) {  return s == "A" ? "5" : std::optional<std::string>{}; }
// ..... more functions like that

struct S {
    int a1;
    const char* a2;
    double a3;
    int64_t a4;
    std::string a5;
private:
    int AGR_INIT_IS_NOT_ALLOWED{0};
};

std::optional<S> getS() {
    auto t = std::make_tuple(get_1("A"), get_2("A"), get_3("A") ,get_4("A") ,get_5("A"));
    if (!std::apply([](auto&&... vals){ return ([](auto&& v){ return v.has_value(); }(vals) && ...);}, t)) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    S s;
    s.a1 = *std::get<0>(t);
    s.a2 = *std::get<1>(t);
    s.a3 = *std::get<2>(t);
    s.a4 = *std::get<3>(t);
    s.a5 = *std::get<4>(t);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    return !getS();
}
```

That's not nice as we've got to execute all the `get_*` functions, even if the first one alrede returned `std::nullopt` (I also don't like to use `std::get` here)

And here I pretty much ran out of any good ideas how to achieve "exception based approach" w/o any exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reducing boilerplate and code duplication like this is still a place where *macros* are a valid solution, as there are no other language features available to do this in a sensible manner.

```
#include <optional>

std::optional<int> get1();
std::optional<int> get2();
std::optional<int> get3();
std::optional<int> get4();

struct S
{
    int i1, i2, i3, i4;
};

std::optional<S> get_s()
{
    #define ASSIGN_OR_FAIL(member, func) \
    { \
        auto opt_val = func(); \
        if (!opt_val) \
            return std::nullopt; \
                             \
        member = *opt_val; \
    } 

    S ret;

    ASSIGN_OR_FAIL(ret.i1, get1)
    ASSIGN_OR_FAIL(ret.i2, get2)
    ASSIGN_OR_FAIL(ret.i3, get3)
    ASSIGN_OR_FAIL(ret.i4, get4)

    return ret;

    #undef ASSIGN_OR_FAIL
}
```

Comment: Yeah, in fact at the end I've decided to go with smth similar

Answer (score 1):

Make a functor template that takes a pointer to a `S::a*` and the corresponding `get_*` function, and put instantiations of it into a vector of `std::function`s. Then you can call each one in a loop.

```
template<typename T, typename F>
struct GetGeneric {
    T* a;
    F get;
    bool operator()(const std::string& s) {
        auto opt = get(s);
        if (opt) { *a = *opt; }
        return opt.has_value();
    }
};

std::optional<S> getS() {
    S s;
    std::vector<std::function<bool(const std::string&)>> get_vector{
        GetGeneric{ &s.a1, get_1 },
        GetGeneric{ &s.a2, get_2 },
        GetGeneric{ &s.a3, get_3 },
        GetGeneric{ &s.a4, get_4 },
        GetGeneric{ &s.a5, get_5 }
    };

    for (auto& f : get_vector) {
        if (!f("A")) {
            return std::nullopt;
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GTja7f18T)

Comment: Why use a `vector`? You know exactly how many elements it must contain which is a compile time constant. It is much better to use an array in this context.

Comment: My the only concern here is possible inderection (virtual calls). Need to have a look if compiler is abale to optimize it

Comment: @Mestkon Mostly because I didn't want to specify that number as template argument. Sure, it might be better in terms of performance, but do you really care in this case? If you do, don't use `std::function` or any kind of type erasure, and instead keep the first version of OP's code.

Comment: @Dmitry I'm afraid if you don't want indirection you need to keep the first version in your question. Possibly with macros, like in Mestkon's answer.

Comment: @Nelfeal Yeah, I'll go with macros stuff. Thank you so much anyway